# Flutter build release apk with no sound null safety?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test, flutter2.0

Debug apk works fine, release apk not working..

Tried flutter build apk --no-sound-null-safety it builds release apk but does not works.

Comment: Please include some code or a description of the sample code and device you are resting on. This doesn't include enough details for anyone to be able to help.

Comment: The code is working totallly fine without any errors. When I am testing debug apk on any real device it also  works fine but when I build the release apk the apk get's installed but does not move respond after entering Login details..

Comment: Please include at least the log, or some error it might occour. Otherwise it is difficult to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue Solved!!
Actually, the problem was with 'http' as SSL certificate was not included for the admin panel hence, app showed
`Bad state: Insecure HTTP is not allowed by platform` error in some devices while it was running in my Mi note4 mobile phone.

Added
 `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` line in
`AndroidManifest.xml` file inside
`<manifest <application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true""> </application> </manifest>` tag

Answer (score 0):

The ability to mix language versions frees package maintainers to migrate their code, with the knowledge that even legacy users can get new bug fixes and other improvements. However, mixed-version programs don’t get all the advantages that null safety can bring. [Read here](https://dart.dev/null-safety/unsound-null-safety)

**Solution**
[image]

[image]

[image]

Code for building APK:
`flutter build apk --no-sound-null-safety`

Answer (score 0):

Edit Configuration -> Addition run arguments

```
--no-sound-null-safety
```

In main.dart file,

```
// @dart=2.9
```

Try

```
flutter build apk --release --no-sound-null-safety
```